# Swagger 2.0 with API 2.o and Odata 3.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, swagger, swashbuckle

I been trying to implement swagger, through [Swashbuckle][1] on my application, but i get no endpoints at all on my swagger ui, and my doc just returns this

```
{
 "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
     "version": "v1",
     "title": "NB.EAM.WebAPI.V4"
  },
  "host": "localhost:24320",
  "schemes": [
     "http"
   ],
  "paths": {},
  "definitions": {}
}
```

In my webApiConfig i set the following configuration from following the dummys

var swagConfig = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:24320");

```
SwaggerConfig.Register();
WebApiConfig.Register(swagConfig);

using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(swagConfig))
{
     server.OpenAsync().Wait();
}
```

My swagger configuration is the standart one created by Swashbuckle:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
.EnableSwagger(c =>
{                       
    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "NB.EAM.WebAPI.Odata");

    var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var commentsFileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".XML";
    var commentsFile = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "bin", commentsFileName);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(commentsFile);

    c.DocumentFilter<ApplyResourceDocumentation>();

    c.CustomProvider(defaultProvider => new ODataSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider, c, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration).Configure(odataConfig =>
    {

        odataConfig.IncludeNavigationProperties();
    }));
})
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
{                        
});
```

Any idea what i might be missing?

Edit:
here is more information about my setting

full code of my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
        conventions.Insert(0, new CompositeKeyRoutingConvention());
        conventions.Insert(1, new CompositeKeyNavigationRoutingConvention());

        conventions.Insert(2, new CountODataRoutingConvention());

        ODataBatchHandler batchHandler = new UnitOfWorkBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);

        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GenerateEdmModel(), new CountODataPathHandler(), conventions, batchHandler);

        config.Filters.Add(new SqlExceptionFilterAttribute());
        config.Filters.Add(new FilterInterceptor());

        InitContentRepository();

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        var swagConfig = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:24320");

        SwaggerConfig.Register();
        WebApiConfig.Register(swagConfig);

        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(swagConfig))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
        }
    }

 public static Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.ContainerName = "NBContext";

        builder.EntitySet<as_portfolio>("as_portfolio");
        builder.EntitySet<cf_usersportfolio>("cf_usersportfolio");
        builder.EntitySet<as_locatportfolio>("as_locatportfolio");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgaset>("ac_bdgaset");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgcc>("ac_bdgcc");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgdtl>("ac_bdgdtl");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgloca>("ac_bdgloca");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgress>("ac_bdgress");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgsect>("ac_bdgsect");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgwoa>("ac_bdgwoa");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgwob>("ac_bdgwob");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgwolb>("ac_bdgwolb");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bdgwost>("ac_bdgwost");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_bgdcc>("ac_bgdcc");
        builder.EntitySet<ac_custome>("ac_custome");
        ----Very long list of enetitySets
        return builder.GetEdmModel();

}
```

An example of my API

```
using NB.EAM.DataV2;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.OData;

namespace NB.EAM.WebAPI.Controllers
{
public class wo_hrtypeController : BaseODataController
{
    // GET: odata/wo_hrtype

    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<wo_hrtype> Getwo_hrtype()
    {
        return this.GetWo_HrtypeBll.GetAll();
    }

    // GET: odata/wo_hrtype(5)
    [Queryable]
    public SingleResult<wo_hrtype> Getwo_hrtype([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(this.GetWo_HrtypeBll.Find(wo_hrtype => 
        wo_hrtype.lb_tyhr == key));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no much information to work there.

We don't know what kind of filters are being aplied on ApplyResourceDocumentation (actually, this class is on the swashbuckle.odata sample proyect and may not fit your necesities:
https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData/blob/master/Swashbuckle.OData.Sample/DocumentFilters/ApplyResourceDocumentation.cs).

We can't also check your entities and function definitions. Check this as an example: https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData/blob/master/Swashbuckle.OData.Sample/App_Start/ODataConfig.cs

And we can't also check if your controllers are defined in a proper way (Methods as verbs. I think custom named methods are only taken into account if they are defined as functions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried the filter but it's not what we were looking for, i added more information on my question.

Comment: I think it could be because of the names of the methods, try using the standard names (just Get, Put, Patch, Post...). I think different names only work as actions/functions defined in the edm.

If that doesn't work you can also try using the ODataRoute attribute in the method (combined or not with ODataRoutePreffix).

Comment: You should also use the [HttpGet] attribute to indicate the verb used to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had a similar issue. Try replacing the following line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(...
```

with this one:

```
swagConfig.EnableSwagger(...
```

The thing is that you should use here the same configuration instance that you pass to the HttpSelfHostServer constructor.

```
SwaggerConfig.Register(swagConfig); // pass the swagConfig instance to the auto-generated method

WebApiConfig.Register(swagConfig);

using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(swagConfig))
{
     server.OpenAsync().Wait();
}
```